# Can I transfer ether from a wallet to smart contract directly without invoking a payable function?

Tags: mist, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, remix, metamask

hey I was trying to pass some ether from my account to smart contract through metamask. Ive already given some ether from my contract to metamask account so it should be possible to do the same even without a payable function.transferring ether to contract through wallet is as easy as transferring ether to any usual account right? But when i send ether it gives me following error-
[image]

Any help would be appreciated thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to send ethers to smart contract you should define a pyable function it could be the fallback function.otherwise you will get an error.